# iTunes cannot find music files after upgrading to Yosemite

Tags: mac, macos

After upgrading from Mavericks to Yosemite, most of my music files appear to have gone missing.

Whenever I try to play music on my Mac, a pop up shows up saying: *"the song you're trying to listen to could not be used because the original file could not be found. Would you like to locate it?"*

And if I choose to locate it, the only thing that happens is the last Finder window I was in re-opens.

How do I get my music back?

Comment: Did you try to rebuild your iTunes library ?

Comment: What do you mean by "rebuild your iTunes library"?

Comment: seethis http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201561 your music files are still there just not connected to iTunes.

Comment: or type .mp3 in finder search (dot)